# Trying to fix a XML DOM parsing error on the fly in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am using an DOM xml reader and data it is reading contains a known XML parsing error. So in Firefox Console it will say ' not well formed ' and then it will list the offending reader with a row and columns. 
If you click on the error it will pop up the actual XML in a pop up window.
I am trying to get access to this original XML text, so I can correct the syntax issue and create a new DOM object.

What I am trying to do is read the XML and I know what this error in the xml is going to be and I want to read the original XML into a string that can manually remove this known error in a string first and then convert it back to an XML DOM object without this parsing error.

The problem is when I try to get serialize the XML it is just returning the error and not the original XML string.  How do I get this original string. The Firefox console window has access to it but I do not know how to do it in Javascript . Thank you

```
            var xmlDoc = http.responseXML;
            if (xmlDoc != null){

                var xmlText = XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xmlDoc);

                // remove bad syntax text
                //var xml = xmlText .replace("badsyntax","");


                //var  parser = new DOMParser();
                //var oc = parser.parseFromString(xml, "text/xml");

            }
```